# IComparer compare value of enum

Tags: c#, enums, icomparable, icomparer

I am implementing a compare method (`IComparer`) for the game Manille and I need to compare certain cards (enum values) with each other.

I want to order them in a certain way so that Number 10 is the biggest card and Ace the second biggest.

There is also a certain symbol that is always higher then other cards (for example Hearts)

**The problem:**

I don't know how to tell that Nummer.Tien is bigger then B, D, H

Also Ace has to be the second highest card, but the algorithm is putting him on the first place.

```
public class ManilleComparer : IComparer<Kaart>
{
        private Kleur symbol; // the symbol that is higher

        public ManilleComparer(Kleur symbol)
        {
            this.symbol = symbol;
        }

        public int Compare(Kaart x, Kaart y)
        {
            int compareTo = x.Kleur.CompareTo(y.Kleur); //check symbols against each other

            if (compareTo == 0) // if value is 0 they have the same symbol
            {
                compareTo = x.Nummer.CompareTo(y.Nummer); // order them 
                return compareTo;
            }

            return x.Nummer.CompareTo(y.Nummer); // else compare values
        }
}

public enum Nummer { Aas, Twee, Drie, Vier, Vijf, Zes, Zeven, Acht, Negen, Tien, Boer, Dame, Heer } // Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Zeven, Eight, Nine, Ten, 11, 12, 13

public enum Kleur { Schoppen, Harten, Klaveren, Ruiten }
```

I have a Sort methot that sorts all the cards in the correct orde, which words fine:

```html
public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            Kaart dezeKaart = this;
            Kaart andereKaart = obj as Kaart;
            int compareTo = dezeKaart.Kleur.CompareTo(andereKaart.Kleur);
            if(compareTo == 0)
            {
                compareTo = dezeKaart.Nummer.CompareTo(andereKaart.Nummer);
                return compareTo;
            }
            return compareTo;
        }
```

The outcome of this sort method is:

```
   // ♠A -  ♠2 -  ♠3 -  ♠4 -  ♠5 -  ♠6 -  ♠7 -  ♠8 -  ♠9 - ♠10 -  ♠B -  ♠D -  ♠H
    // ♥A -  ♥2 -  ♥3 -  ♥4 -  ♥5 -  ♥6 -  ♥7 -  ♥8 -  ♥9 - ♥10 -  ♥B -  ♥D -  ♥H
    // ♣A -  ♣2 -  ♣3 -  ♣4 -  ♣5 -  ♣6 -  ♣7 -  ♣8 -  ♣9 - ♣10 -  ♣B -  ♣D -  ♣H
    // ♦A -  ♦2 -  ♦3 -  ♦4 -  ♦5 -  ♦6 -  ♦7 -  ♦8 -  ♦9 - ♦10 -  ♦B -  ♦D -  ♦H

I now want to implement Icompare
to have this as an outcome:

    // ♦7 -  ♦8 -  ♦9 -  ♦B -  ♦D -  ♦H -  ♦A - ♦10
    // ♣7 -  ♣8 -  ♣9 -  ♣B -  ♣D -  ♣H -  ♣A - ♣10
    // ♠7 -  ♠8 -  ♠9 -  ♠B -  ♠D -  ♠H -  ♠A - ♠10
    // ♥7 -  ♥8 -  ♥9 -  ♥B -  ♥D -  ♥H -  ♥A - ♥10
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Sorry, updated my post

Comment: Well, give your enumeration members values that enforces the card value hierarchy. You know you can do that, right? `enum MyEnum { One = 1, Three = 3, //etc. }`

Comment: I know but that will mess up my other Sort method, which the outcome must be:
 // ♠A -  ♠2 -  ♠3 -  ♠4 -  ♠5 -  ♠6 -  ♠7 -  ♠8 -  ♠9 - ♠10 -  ♠B -  ♠D -  ♠H
            // ♥A -  ♥2 -  ♥3 -  ♥4 -  ♥5 -  ♥6 -  ♥7 -  ♥8 -  ♥9 - ♥10 -  ♥B -  ♥D -  ♥H
  ...

And this sort method must be:
// ♦7 -  ♦8 -  ♦9 -  ♦B -  ♦D -  ♦H -  ♦A - ♦10
            // ♣7 -  ♣8 -  ♣9 -  ♣B -  ♣D -  ♣H -  ♣A - ♣10
            // ♠7 -  ♠8 -  ♠9 -  ♠B -  ♠D -  ♠H -  ♠A - ♠10
            // ♥7 -  ♥8 -  ♥9 -  ♥B -  ♥D -  ♥H -  ♥A - ♥10

Comment: What other sort method? You should put all relevant info in your question.

Comment: Yeah I know, first time :( sorry..

Comment: Test your code by creating only two cards (the ones that don't work) and debug your code. See where the logic is wrong and fix it.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing, but I dont know how to tell the Sort method that Nummer.Tien is higher than Nummer.H for example

Comment: Well what is the return value of the `Compare` method supposed to be when Tien and H are passed? What if H and Tien are passed instead? What if H and H is passed?

Comment: You can have more than one Enumerator and more than one IComparer class, that perform different comparisons in different scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
    public class ManilleComparer : IComparer<Kaart>
                {
                    public ManilleComparer(){}

                    public ManilleComparer(List<Kleur> PrefKleurRank)
                    {
                        KleurRank = PrefKleurRank;
                    }

                    public ManilleComparer(Kleur LastColor)
                    {
                        KleurRank.Remove(LastColor);
                        KleurRank.Add(LastColor);
                    }

                    private List<Kleur> KleurRank = new List<Kleur>() { Kleur.Ruiten , Kleur.Klaveren, Kleur.Schoppen, Kleur.Harten };
                    private List<Nummer> NummerRank = new List<Nummer>() { Nummer.Twee, Nummer.Drie, Nummer.Vier, Nummer.Vier, Nummer.Zes, Nummer.Zeven,  Nummer.Acht, Nummer.Negen, Nummer.Boer, Nummer.Dame, Nummer.Heer, Nummer.Aas, Nummer.Tien };

                    public int Compare(Kaart x, Kaart y)
                    {
                        int compareTo = KleurRank.IndexOf(x.Kleur).CompareTo(KleurRank.IndexOf(y.Kleur)); //check symbols against each other

                        if (compareTo == 0) // if value is 0 they have the same symbol
                        {
                            compareTo = NummerRank.IndexOf(x.Nummer).CompareTo(NummerRank.IndexOf(y.Nummer));  
                        }

                        return compareTo; 
                    }
                }
```

you can also pass the order to the contructor to be more flexible

This is how to use it:

```
                Kaart k1 = new Kaart() { Kleur = Kleur.Ruiten, Nummer = Nummer.Drie };
                Kaart k2 = new Kaart() { Kleur = Kleur.Harten, Nummer = Nummer.Heer };
                Kaart k3 = new Kaart() { Kleur = Kleur.Ruiten, Nummer = Nummer.Aas };

                Kaart.ManilleComparer m = new Kaart.ManilleComparer();

                List<Kaart> mylist = new List<Kaart>();
                mylist.Add(k1);
                mylist.Add(k2);
                mylist.Add(k3);

                mylist.Sort(m);

                private List<Kleur> MyKleurRank = new List<Kleur>() { Kleur.Ruiten , Kleur.Klaveren, Kleur.Harten , Kleur.Schoppen};

                Kaart.ManilleComparer m2 = new Kaart.ManilleComparer(MyKleurRank);

                mylist.Sort(m2);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you reply, I appreciate it! However I'm confused of what NummerRank and KleurRank are?

Comment: This is your prefered order which you want to have your cards and colors. Look at the order of them compared to how you want to have them sorted, it is equal. I am using it to get the index of the cards which I compare.

Comment: It is returning that KleurRank and NummerRank does not exist in current context

Comment: You have any idea how i can manipulate this code so when I call the class -> 
manilleDek.Sort(new ManilleComparer(Kleur.Schoppen));
It will put Kleur.Schoppen at the bottom instead of Hearths?

Comment: You are then better of passing the KleurRank in the contructor, I add it to my answer.

Comment: I cant change what is passed into  the constructor  (not allowed), it has the be an enum value :/

Comment: Who is creating this limitation? :-)

Comment: Implementation of the UI

Comment: See added contructor